# Add serial number to <tr> in ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

Iam using ajax to to dynamically generate table rows. I want to add serial number with every table row ie - td1. Everything else is working fine, please help me to add serial number with every tr.

```
< script >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            ajx();
        });

        function ajx() {
            $('tbody>tr').remove();
            var side = $('input[name=pins]:checked').val();
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('#loader').show();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('#loader').hide();
                },
                url: "<?php echo base_url('user/genealogy/ajaxLevels')?>",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    side: side
                },
                success: function (result)
                {

                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));
                    var id = "#tbl";
                    $.each(obj, function () {
                        var row = $('<tr>');
                        var td1 = $('<td />');
                        var td2 = $('<td />');
                        var td3 = $('<td />');
                        var td4 = $('<td />');
                        var td5 = $('<td />');

                        td1.text('1'); // I WANT TO ADD SERIAL NUMBER HERE
                        td2.text(this.name);
                        td3.text(this.id);
                        td4.text(this.date);
                        td5.text(this.sponsor_id);

                        row.append(td1);
                        row.append(td2);
                        row.append(td3);
                        row.append(td4);
                        row.append(td5);

                        $(id).append(row);
                    });
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

This is the table in which data is going to be shown :

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="text-primary">
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Member ID</th>
        <th>DOJ</th>
        <th>Sponser ID</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want the numbers to be like 1,2,3,4... or something else?

Comment: Yes, 1,2,3,4,5,6......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a variable setted to `1` as a start value.
Then increment this variable on each iteration.

```
success: function (result)
  {

    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(result));
    var id = "#tbl";

    // use i as a counter
    var i = 1;

    $.each(obj, function () {
      var row = $('<tr>');
      var td1 = $('<td />');
      var td2 = $('<td />');
      var td3 = $('<td />');
      var td4 = $('<td />');
      var td5 = $('<td />');

      td1.text(i); // Use i here
      td2.text(this.name);
      td3.text(this.id);
      td4.text(this.date);
      td5.text(this.sponsor_id);

      row.append(td1);
      row.append(td2);
      row.append(td3);
      row.append(td4);
      row.append(td5);

      $(id).append(row);

      // Increment i for the next iteration
      i++;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quite easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$.each(obj, function (key,value) {
```

You can use `key + 1` to display serial number. In each function Key is always start from 0.